# Azure VM: Can't access/ping port 80

Tags: iis, azure, webserver, virtual-machine, windows-server-2008-r2

I am new to the Azure platform so hopefully this is an easy question:

I am currently setting up a Sharepoint web farm through Azure. My current architecture looks like this:

- A WIN2008 VM serving as my Domain Controller. I have the domain setup and AD running
- A WIN2008 VM SQL2012 serving as my db server
- A WIN2008 VM serving as my sharepoint web server.

All of the VMs belong to the domain.

I have sharepoint up and running on the sharepoint web server and I can access the sharepoint sites using //localhost. However, I cannot access the sites from an external computer (port 80). I cannot ping it with the IP Address or the *.cloudapp.net address. I have already ensured the firewall ports for 80 are open for all profiles. I have also setup an endpoint for port 80 on the sharepoint VM.

Any thoughts? I appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: have you tried checking your SharePoint Alternate Access Mappings or IIS Site Bindings?

Comment: So, I was making this more difficult than it needed to be. For anybody else out there like me, what happened was that Azure VMs do not allow pinging. That's why I wasn't able to ping the server. Entering the address in the browser URL worked fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that Azure will block ping requests

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/7ce4e4c5-c714-492f-8cd6-424c01552195

Answer (score 8):

To elaborate on the endpoint reference above:

There is a configuration page in the Azure portal that you need to check out to ensure that the proper ports are open AS WELL AS the ones on the Endpoints page for your windows VM. I assume the same would apply for other hosted OS VMs like Linux, etc.

[image: Look on the status page of your VM]

When I came across the Endpoints tab for the VM in question on the Azure portal I noticed that there were RDP and PowerShell ports listed but no HTTP. After adding that I found that I could hit my IIS server on the VM. In a nutshell its like there are two firewalls, the one on your server and one on the Azure portal.

Comment: Very true, also make sure the Firewall allows port 80.

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you have an answer, but of note is that you have to set up endpoints for anything that you want to hit.

Comment: Thanks!  I wasted an hour or two before coming across this.